# Windows Server 2019 Prevent Duplicate Files from being created as well as configuring group permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am adding a new folder structure to Windows Server as a file share. I have several user (security) groups: estimators, project managers, and salespeople. Each group has users in it. However, when I assign advanced NTFS permissions to the folder structure using any one of these groups, the users in the group cannot access the share although I can grant each user permissions and it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, is there a way to tell Windows Server to prevent duplicate files from being created in a file share?